# how to add a empty string as default in the drop down where dropdown is a directive

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive

In my AngularJS project, I am having a dropdown field as a directive and the values are coming from the backend.The user can also leave the field without selecting the dropdown(optional field) but the problem is, there is no empty field from the backend. So I need to add an empty field into the dropdown as default.

Since there is no option in the directive got struck in this issue.Googled a lot but didnt get any solutions yet.Kindly provide some suggestion.

Note:Client machine,cant post the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no value set for the ng-model that the dropdown is bound to, Angular will provide a blank option by default that can be left in place (ignored) by the user and will result in your final value being whatever you set that ng-model to in the first place. If you need an actual empty string for the value, initialize it to that.

If you need to enable the user to select an empty value once they have already selected a value, you will need to add an empty value to the object that the dropdown is bound to. Add the empty value like this:

```
myPromise.then(function(data){
    $scope.ddInfo = data;
    $scope.ddInfo.unshift({id:'0000',text:'Not Applicable'});
});
```

Comment: I have added the following code to the index 0. But i am unable to  select any values. getting digest error while trying to select any value from the dropdown. emptyTitleValue[0]={id: '0000', text: 'Not Applicable'};